# What was the implication of Quaternions in modern (21th) physics and usage in electrodynamics in 19th century?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, history, complex-numbers

I'm doing a study about number theory in physics where I put some focus into the usage of Quaternions.  See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Use_in_physics

Right now I conclude that the quaternion carried the fundamental implication towards the space-time structure in GR minkowski space.

However, I also read that the quaternions had an important role in electrodynamics in the 19th century before the appearance of Maxwell equation.

My question was that:

1. Could you tell my why quaternions were so important for electrodynamics before maxwell?
2. I read that as the advancing of modern physics, the role of quaternions had become a little bit "fading away", could you explain a bit why that was the case?
3. What's the popular view of quaternions in recent year? Do we have a more fundamental understanding towards it?

Comment: hopefully you are aware of Micael Crowe's work? http://worrydream.com/refs/Crowe-HistoryOfVectorAnalysis.pdf